# Calling a click event of a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to all things javascript related, and I seem to have got myself in a pickle. I'm creating a site which displays a seating plan of an office. When the page loads, I load data retrieved from the database, into a function that loops through it and creates an anchor for each person.

This is my method:

```
       function getDesks(coordsArr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < coordsArr.length; i++) {
                var element = $("<a href='' class='deskBtn' data-name='" + coordsArr[i].UserName + "'>.</a>");
                $(element).css({
                    "top": coordsArr[i].DeskYCoord,
                    "left": coordsArr[i].DeskXCoord
                }).appendTo(".map");
            } 
        }
```

The problem i'm having is where to place the following ajax click event.

```
  $('.deskBtn').on('click', function () {
                var user = $(this).attr("data-name");
                console.log(user);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetUserData",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {user: user},
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            });
```

I tried placing it after the for loop, but when I click one of the anchor tags the data gets logged to the screen, however, it quickly vanishes. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: `.on()` *must* be attached to the parent container, for dynamically added events. Like: `$("#container").on( 'click', '.deskBtn', function(){ });`

Comment: You can create the element with the event too: `var $el = $('<a/>', {class:'deskBtn', click:function(){}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just add the handler inside the for loop?

```
$(element).on('click', function() { ... })
```

Comment: Hi Jared, I added the click event inside the loop, but when I click on one of the links, the user data is displayed,however, it quickly disappears and the ajax call is never made.

Comment: you must add `return false;` just before the function closes. Otherwise,the browser attempts to follow the link `href` which, in this case left blank, means to attempt to load the same page URL again. If you were to change `href=''` to `href='#'` you'll find the `$.ajax` fires.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event to a static element. Do it for `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deskBtn', function () {

    var user = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(user);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetUserData",
        type: "GET",
        data: {user: user},
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a live

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.deskBtn').live('click', function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: good thought, though `.live()` has been deprecated and replaced by `.on()` as of 1.7 http://api.jquery.com/live/